# How to set the DynamicSelect expression in Modelica models

Tags: modelica, dymola

I plan to show a variable's quantity in a text string, so I checked the usage of DynamicSelect expression in [Modelica Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf), as shown below:

[image]

Here is an example I make, it only contains one Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine component and a text label, but I am not sure why the text doesn't change during the simulation. It seems like the DynamicSelect expression doesn't work at all.
My question is:
How should I set the DynamicSelect expression to make it work?

```
model fsdaf

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine(amplitude=100, freqHz=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-124,-10},{-104,10}})));
equation 

  annotation (Diagram(graphics={
          Text(
          extent={{-22,60},{98,10}},
          lineColor={28,108,200},
          fillColor={238,46,47},
          fillPattern=FillPattern.None,
          textString=DynamicSelect(10,string(sine.y)))}),
          uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end fsdaf;
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out that I need to use `String()` instead of `string()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Please use `String()` for conversion of numeric values to string.
- Browse the [Modelica Standard Library](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/search?q=DynamicSelect&type=code) which uses DynamicSelect in various places.
- Here is an improved example for Modelica Standard Library version 4 with slowed down simulation:

```
model TestDynamicSelect
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine(amplitude=100, f=1) annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,40},{-60,60}})));
  Modelica_DeviceDrivers.Blocks.OperatingSystem.RealtimeSynchronize realtimeSynchronize annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,0},{-60,20}})));
  annotation(experiment(StopTime=10), Diagram(graphics={
   Text(
     extent={{-22,60},{98,10}},
     lineColor={28,108,200},
     fillColor={238,46,47},
     fillPattern=FillPattern.None,
     textString=DynamicSelect(10,String(sine.y)))}),
   uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0"), Modelica_DeviceDrivers(version="2.0.0")));
end TestDynamicSelect;
```